# Preinstalled Windows 7 vs. Vendor Win10 on DVD vs. Win10 from Microsoft

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, license, setup, product-key

I bought a new HP ProDesk 400. This machine has a preinstalled Windows 7 Pro, which I could setup manually. I also got a Windows 10 Pro DVD from HP (labeled 'DVD-Kit 836297-DW2')

I don't see any COA from Microsoft on the case.

My questions are:

a) Can I install the Windows 10 Pro DVD pro directly, without prior setup of the preinstalled Win 7 Pro?

b) Can I install an official Microsoft MSDN Windows 10 Pro directly, even if I don't have a Product Key for Windows 10 Pro (assuming, the necessary key is stored in the BIOS/UEFI)?

Comment: If the machine came with Windows 7 then HP provided a COA for Windows 7.  The Windows 10 key is embedded in the ACPI table.  There is no difference between the Windows 10 DVD that HP provided you and the .ISO you can download except perhaps when it was and which build it would install.  If you don't have a COA for Windows 7 then  contact HP, its not clear how you got a brand new computer with Windows 7, when HP does not sell Windows 7 computers currently.  *They literally cannot purchase more licenses from Microsoft.*

Answer (score 1):

- If the HP advertised that you could install Win 10 on your PC, without further precisions, the DVD they provided is supposed to handle everything, including finding the appropriate product key.
- Before assuming your computer has a product key stored in its BIOS, check it. I suggest you use [RWEverything](http://rweverything.com/), then go to *Access* --> *ACPI Tables* --> *MSDM* --> *Data*. The product key is shown there, if it's in the BIOS. Then you can use this key to install Windows 10 with a genuine DVD (such as MSDN). *Don't overwrite the Win 7 partitions before you make sure you can use this key.*
- If none of the above works for you, wait for your Windows Update to download the free upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "wait for your free upgrade to Windows 10". Now - in the middle of August 2016 - there is no free upgrade anymore. Could you please explain that part?